# GridView scroll position

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview which is populated with 10 images, when I scroll down to the last item and change the data completely, this way:

```
gridAdapter.values.clear();
gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and add completely new set of 10 images.

The problem is, by default the gridView is scrolled to the bottom most item, may be because the previous scroll position was that. Its same like you scroll through a list -> click on item -> click back and the **browser** tries to scroll to the previous scroll position.

How can I show the top more item, instead of this behavior.

Comment: Is your goal to have like infinite grid with only 10 items in adapter max and user able to scroll it without noticing any difference?

Comment: No, I want the gridview to stay on top most item, when ever I clear the data and add new data.

Comment: Have you tried scrollTo(0) after setting new data?

Comment: There is no such funtion

Comment: GridView should have that method

Comment: scrollTo(0, 0) to be exact with both new x and y values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int pos = gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 
gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
```

When you are returning from another activity.

Comment: This is kind of shows the last item and then scrolls to the top. Instead how can I avoid showing the last item?

Comment: You could try adding a GlobalLayoutListener to the GridView it's ViewTreeObserver, in the listener try to do this or set the position on 0. Like: gridView.setPosition(0) (something like that).

Answer (score 0):

When in bottom you can call:

```
gridView.setAdapter(null);
gridView.setAdapter(prevAdapterWithNewItems);
```

However this doesn't abort user scrolling or fling effect.

Comment: I am doing the same, it works fine, except that the `GridView` by default shows the last scroll position instead of starting from the top(like a listview).

Comment: Hmm okay, I need to reproduce the issue myself to find working solution, I will be visiting work later today and post it then here.

Comment: Do you want the grid to stop when you set new items (abort fling/user scroll) ?